# Hows does firebase firestore read counted?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Please someone help me to know how does the firebase firestore read counted.
I noticed that whenever i view my data in firebase console that too taken as in "read" so my doubt is whether i would be charged when my client view the fetched data in the app too! initially i thought that
i would be charged only for the "read" done by the user in my app. I know that 1 document is equal to one read, but i never knew that read is also counted when we actually see the data in the firebase console.
so please help me to know the right way to use it, this is creating a headache for me. and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're [charged for reads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) in the console too. Generally, this number is low during the development phase and should easily be covered by the free trial.

If your documents are excessive, you may prefer building a separate admin dashboard for him/her. Using

If you are charged heavily just **for opening the firestore console**, you may consider creating a blank collection with the name `a` - so that whenever you load firestore console, only documents in the `a` collection are loaded.

[image: 3 Firebase collection, first starting with a]

Comment: Thank you but can you explain me how the dashboard will solve my problem because it will also fetch data from firestore pls explain and thank you so much !!

Comment: That is a minimum charge that you might need to pay. Even if you were using a SQL Database - you are charged for "viewing" the database in phpmyadmin or pgAdmin viewers.

Answer (score 2):

One Firestore document read is counted (and charged if you have reached the [free quota limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) of 50K/day for reads) **in both cases**: the document is read from the Firebase Console **or** the document is read from your app.

---

> help me to know the right way to use it

There is no real "right way". You are charged one document read each time you read a Firestore doc (whatever is the way of reading it) and you have reached the [free quota limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) (i.e. 50K/day for reads)

You will find more details in the dedicated [Firestore doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Comment: What if I just opened collection and not any documents data inside means I am not reading any document data but getting a list of documents

Comment: What you exactly mean by «open a collection »? If you execute a query to get a `QuerySnapshot` you pay for every doc in the snapshot. And if it is empty you pay for one doc read. Look at the doc for more details, see the link above. If the answer helped you, please upvote it. Thx